# How to use relative urls without canonical and prev-next?

Tags: rel-canonical

I want to use relative urls instead of absolute urls but not all types. Here's just a few examples.

Exclude:
canonical urls, prev and next post like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/title/" />
<link rel='prev' title='title 2' href='https://www.example.com/title-2/' />
<link rel='next' title='title 3' href='https://www.example.com/title-3/' />
```

Include:
All categories, menu, posts, pages, js, css, wp-content/uploads, etc.

That's what I need.

Comment: WP Core uses absolute links, so changing would be a manual process. For example, when you link within a post, you would type in the relative path instead of choosing a post/page to link to from their search or list. And in the menus, instead of using post IDs, you could use "custom links" that use relative paths. Unfortunately, this approach is fragile as it won't automatically update URLs when anything changes, so you may want to stick to Core's absolute paths. I prefer relative too (especially when swapping between staging and prod) but it's so built into Core it's hard to overcome.